# Connecting to MongoDB running in a Docker Container using persistence.xml

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, docker, jboss, wildfly

I have a Java EE 11 application deployed and running on JBoss WildFly 16.0.0.Final in a Docker Container.

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
>   NAMES 867d2b0c179b        gostophandle:latest   "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"
>   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:32826->8080/tcp
>   elegant_shtern

I have an instance of MongoDB also running in a Docker Container.

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
>   1c064a161638        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2
>   minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        27017/tcp           goStopHandle

This is my 'persistence.xml' which I use to connect to a 'localhost' instance of MongoDB:

```
<persistence-unit name="goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

        <properties>

            <!-- <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2"/> -->
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.3"/>

            <!-- <property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="org.hibernate.search.orm:5.8"/> -->
            <property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="org.hibernate.search.orm:5.10"/>

            <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="JBossTS"/> -->
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAS"/> -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.grid_dialect" value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.MongoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="goStopHandleDB"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="127.0.0.1:27017"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

I've ran:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' aea9f245ff90
```

and got the IP address of the MongoDB container:

```
172.17.0.2
```

I changed the persistence.xml to use:

```
<property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="172.17.0.2:27017"/>
```

When I start my WildFly container I get:

```
[0m[0m19:39:18,823 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='5ca50be6c9e77c00671d9ec5', description='null'}-gostophandle:27017) Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server gostophandle:27017: com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: gostophandle: Name or service not known
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gostophandle: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203)
    ... 5 more

[0m[0m19:39:19,327 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='5ca50be6c9e77c00671d9ec5', description='null'}-gostophandle:27017) Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server gostophandle:27017: com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: gostophandle
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gostophandle
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203)
    ... 5 more

[0m[0m19:39:28,841 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='5ca50be6c9e77c00671d9ec5', description='null'}-gostophandle:27017) Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server gostophandle:27017: com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: gostophandle: Name or service not known
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gostophandle: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203)
    ... 5 more

[0m[0m19:39:29,344 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (cluster-ClusterId{value='5ca50be6c9e77c00671d9ec5', description='null'}-gostophandle:27017) Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server gostophandle:27017: com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: gostophandle
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gostophandle
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.4@5.4.1.Final//com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203)
    ... 5 more
```

Any suggestions on how I should configure the 'persistence.xml'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the problem I was having when trying to connect to the MongoDB container using Robo 3T.

Need to expose the port:

```
docker run --name my-mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo
```

Now both Robo 3T & my EAR connect to the MongoDB database.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that something is wrong with the MongoClient generated by Hibernate OGM.
One way to approach this is to make sure that the configuration you have used for the client is correct, maybe with a test that creates a client and check that it connects properly.
Than apply the same configuration using the properties in OGM. You can set the property for the driver using the prefix `hibernate.ogm.mongodb.driver.*`. For a list of all the properties available in OGM I will let you to the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#_configuring_mongodb

You can also extends the class `MongoDBDatastoreProvider` and overrides the method:

```
  protected MongoClient createMongoClient(MongoDBConfiguration config) { ... }
```

Then pass the new class to the property `hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider`.